# Sampling a proportion from a population data frame in R (random sampling in stratified sampling)

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sampling

i have a data frame (population) with 3 groups.
I want :

**A)** to take the 0.05 % of each category and
**B)** to take different proportion from each group.

my data frame population is :

```
category = c(rep("a",15),rep("b",30),rep("c",50))
num = c(rnorm(15,0,1),rnorm(30,5,1),rnorm(50,10,1))
pop = data.frame(category,num);pop
```

i am thinking of the `sample_n()` function from dplyr but how can i take the 0.05% of each group?

in the code below i take 5 elements at random from each group.

```
pop%>%
  group_by(category)%>%
  sample_n(size = 5)
```

and how i can change the prop allocation say 0.05% from category a, 0.1 % from b and 20% from c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dataframe with category and respective proportions, join it with `pop` and use `sample_n` to select rows in each group by its respective proportion.

```
library(dplyr)

prop_table <- data.frame(category = c('a','b', 'c'), prop = c(0.005, 0.001, 0.2))

pop %>%
  left_join(prop_table, by = 'category') %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  sample_n(n() * first(prop)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-prop)
```

Note that `sample_n` has been replaced with `slice_sample` but `slice_sample` needs fixed `prop` value for each category and does not allow using something like `first(prop)`.

Comment: So given a stratification in a population in categories (strata) a can use your code to random sample (discrete uniform distribution)  from each category (within category) ?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `slice_sample_n()`:

`sample_n()` and `sample_frac()` have been superseded in favour of `slice_sample()`

```
library(dplyr)
slice_sample(pop, prop=0.05)
slice_sample(pop[pop$category =="a",], prop=0.05)
slice_sample(pop[pop$category =="b",], prop=0.1)
slice_sample(pop[pop$category =="c",], prop=0.2)
```

```
slice_sample(pop, prop=0.05)
  category       num
1        c 10.065583
2        c  9.715412
3        b  4.695062
4        a -1.799090
> slice_sample(pop[pop$category =="a",], prop=0.05)
[1] category num     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> slice_sample(pop[pop$category =="b",], prop=0.1)
  category      num
1        b 5.595527
2        b 4.695062
3        b 6.123029
> slice_sample(pop[pop$category =="c",], prop=0.2)
   category       num
1         c  9.826321
2         c 10.682646
3         c  9.715412
4         c  9.871122
5         c 10.821703
6         c 10.890810
7         c 10.357713
8         c  9.579069
9         c 10.958487
10        c  9.939990
```